# generate response HTTPResponseMessage to the given format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

want to get the response of web api method as given below.
Trying to use HttpResponseMessage but its not generating properly in a json format.

```
{
    "Version": {
        "_Major": 1,
        "_Minor": 1,
        "_Build": -1,
        "_Revision": -1
    },
    "Content": {
        "Headers": [
            {
                "Key": "Content-Type",
                "Value": [
                    "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "StatusCode": 400,
    "ReasonPhrase": "<error reason>",
    "Headers": [],
    "RequestMessage": null,
    "IsSuccessStatusCode": false
}
```

Comment: Did you try returning an object model that fit that json?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Can we return a httpResponseObject with all these values in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
First created a httpResponseObject and populated the properties with respective values.
Then passed the object to request.CreateResponse, it will return the expected result.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the objects below and return them:

```cs
public class Version {
  public int _Major {get; set;}
  public int _Minor{get; set;}
  public int _Build{get; set;}
  public int _Revision{get; set;}
}
public class HttpReturnMessage {
  public Version Version {get; set;}
  public int StatusCode {get; set;}
  public string ReasonPhrase {get; set;}
  public string[] Headers {get; set;}
  public object RequestMessage {get; set;}
  public bool IsSuccessStatusCode {get; set;}
}
```

and create the item in the controller and return it:

```cs
HttpReturnMessage message = new HttpReturnMessage {
  Version = new Version {
    _Major= 1,
    _Minor = 1,
    _Build = 1,
    _Revision = 1
  },
  StatusCode = 300, 
...
};
```

and return this as json

Comment: FYI: you just recreated the [HttpResponseMessage class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This is what httpResponseMessage class is. Why should we create it again.